# Javascript remove whitespaces in `strings`

Tags: javascript, html, string

I JavaScript the ` is very useful when writing big strings. My problem is that it takes into account the amount of white space before it in the JavaScript. So if your string is indented in the JavaScript, then it will be indented in the string as well. Is there any way to get rid of this?

Because in an example like this I would like the html tag to be flush against the left side in the string, but I do not want to make it flush against the left side in the JavaScript. Check how the console.log turns out to understand it better.

```js
MyFunction = function() {
  console.log(`
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
}

MyFunction();
```

**console.log:**

[image]

Comment: What do you want to have happen on the <head> line? Full spaces, no spaces, or just the amount that it's indented relative to <html> (2, it looks like)?

Comment: The amount that i's indented relative to <html> (which is 2 yes :) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want them `html` tag to be flush against the left side, but still want `head` and `body` indented relatively, what you're looking for is to replace set of 4 spaces in the beginning of each line with an empty string.

```
string.replace(/^ {4}/gm, '')
```

Here's the live code ..

```js
MyFunction = function() {
  console.log(`
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
  `.replace(/^ {4}/gm, ''));
}

MyFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) the white spaces?

```js
MyFunction = function() {
  console.log(`
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
  `.trim());
}

MyFunction();
```

If you want auto indentations for all of your tags i would go for a library, maybe something like [pretty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty).

No need to invent the wheel here.

Comment: I think they also want to have the spaces shortened after the linebreaks too

Comment: Hmm, according to the image the OP uploaded i was under the impression only the start `html` tag is in question

Comment: I'll ask for clarification :)

Comment: No no not only the start `html` tag. Everything should move back. I can only highlight one part at a time with my mouse selection which is why I only highlighted the first part haha....good answer though in the way you understood it!

Comment: but you still want indentations or you want all the lines to start at the same point (0 column from the left?)

Comment: I still want indentations hey. Just the <html> and </html> tags must be against the left (0 column)

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
MyFunction = function() {
  /*however many spaces you want to remove from the front*/
  const spaces = '    '; // four spaces
  /* or */
  const spacesRegex = /\s+/g;
  let str = '';
  const html = `
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
  `.split('\n')
  .forEach(line=>{
    str += line.replace(spaces, '') + '\n';
  });
  console.log(str);

}
```

Comment: Did you test this? I can't get this to work correctly. I copy and pasted the code. Added `MyFunction()` but the result only removes the first <html> tag's spaces

Comment: @FreddyBonda, I haven't. I have edited the code after testing.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple regex to find the initial indentation of the string can be done with `/^[\r\n]?(\s+)/` - the result can be used to again do a line-for line replacement of the initial indent. Also this takes advantage of the performance of JS RegExp.

If you also want the first and last line breakes removed, just add `.trim()` after the string replacement.

```js
function trimLeadingWS(str) {
  /*
    Get the initial indentation
    But ignore new line characters
  */
  var matcher = /^[\r\n]?(\s+)/;
  if(matcher.test(str)) {
    /*
      Replace the initial whitespace 
      globally and over multiple lines
    */
    return str.replace(new RegExp("^" + str.match(matcher)[1], "gm"), "");
  } else {
    // Regex doesn't match so return the original string
    return str;
  }
};

MyFunction = function() {
  console.log(trimLeadingWS('nothing to trim'));
  console.log(trimLeadingWS(`
                    really 
                      quite
                        some
                          of                    (amount of spaces after line break should be ignored)
                        indent
                      to 
                    remove
  `));
  console.log(trimLeadingWS(`
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
  `));
}

MyFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split text by `\n`, find indentation in first revelant line and remove it from the rest of line, then join it again.

```js
MyFunction = function () {
 let indent = "";
 console.log(`
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
  `.split("\n").reduce((lines, line) => {
  if (!indent.length && line.trim()) {
   indent = line.match(/^(\s+)/)[0];
  }
  lines.push(line.replace(indent, ""));
  return lines;
 }, []).filter(line => line.length).join("\n"));
};
MyFunction();
```

Comment: But I would like to keep the <head> and <body> tags indented relative to the <html> tags. Like in my example (kinda)

Comment: @FreddyBonda Like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can `match` the spaces after new lines and get the length of the first one. From that you can build a regex that can replace them:

```js
let MyFunction = function(str) {
    let matches = str.match(/ +/g)
    let initial = matches[0].length         // how big is the indent
    let re = RegExp(`\n {${initial}}`, 'g') // remove these at the beginning of lines
    return str.replace(re, '\n')
  }

let str = `
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
           some text
        </div>
    </body>
  </html>
`  
console.log(MyFunction(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are, of course, a thousand ways to get to your destination. To make only the indent of the content disappear you can use the following method with your template strings. This ensures that only the indent created by the template string disappears, but the basic formatting remains intact.

```js
function trimIndent(strings, ...values) {
    const result = new Array(strings.length);
    result[0] = strings[0].replace(/^\n/, '');
    const endIndex = strings.length - 1;
    result[endIndex] = strings[endIndex].replace(/\n$/, '');

    var indent = result[0].match(/^\s+/g);
    result[0] = result[0].replace(/^\s+/, '');

    for (let i = 0, m = result.length; i < m; i++) {
        var input = result[i] ?? strings[i];
        result[i] = input.replace(new RegExp('\n' + indent, "gm"), '\n');
    }

    return result.flatMap((value, index) => {
        return value + (index < values.length ? values[index] : '')
    }).join("");
}

// example call:
var user = {
  id: 10,
  name: "Kevin",
  
}
if (true) {
  console.log(trimIndent`
      <div>
        <span>ID: ${user.id}</span>
        <span>
          Username: ${user.name}
        </span>
      </div>
  `);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript solution, removes common indentation from the string:

```
/**
 * Remove common indentation from a string
 * @param str The string to deindent
 * @param tabSize The size of the tab
 * @returns The deindented string
 */
export function deindent(strings: TemplateStringsArray, { tabSize = 2 } = {}) {
  let str = strings.join('');
  str = str.replace(/\t/g, ' '.repeat(tabSize));

  const maxCommonIndent = str
    .split('\n')
    .filter((line) => line.trim() !== '')
    .map((line) => line.match(/^ */)![0].length)
    .reduce((max, indent) => Math.max(max, indent), 0);

  return str
    .split('\n')
    .map((line) => line.slice(maxCommonIndent))
    .join('\n');
}
```

Example:

```js
function deindent(strings, { tabSize = 2 } = {}) {
  let str = strings.join('');
  str = str.replace(/\t/g, ' '.repeat(tabSize));

  const minCommonIndent = str
    .split('\n')
    .filter((line) => line.trim() !== '')
    .map((line) => line.match(/^ */)[0].length)
    .reduce((min, indent) => Math.min(min, indent), Infinity);

  return str
    .split('\n')
    .map((line) => line.slice(minCommonIndent))
    .join('\n');
}


console.log(deindent`
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div>
          Hello World!
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
`);
```